# Is there any way to enforce a single user logged in via MSAL 2?

Tags: azure-ad-msal

Library: MSAL 2, via `msal-browser` NPM package. 
Framework: Vue 2 
Components: MGT components for user data retrieval

We have a business use case that requires us to only allow one user to log in. This requires us to log out all other users. The login and logout approach requires redirect auth code flow with PKCE. One approach we have considered is to use `logoutRedirect` and loop over the active user accounts to force logout all other users except the user that just logged in. Curious if there is anything available similar to the [SinglePublicClientApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.identity.client.singleaccountpublicclientapplication?view=azure-java-stable) for Android which will work on mobile and desktop browsers.